# Accessing second time -> 504 exception while getInputStream() from URLConnection

Tags: java, jsp, url, httpurlconnection

Getting 504 exception while accessing second time of getting input stream from URLConnection. When my system is restarted when im accessing the specific url its working well, but when accessing second time it throws an error.

Note :

```
Using Tomcat 6, Java, JSP
```

Code bellow :

```
    OutputStream outStream = null;
    URLConnection uCon = null;

    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        URL Url;
        byte[] buf;
        int ByteRead, ByteWritten = 0;
        Url = new URL("www.sample.com/download/file.xml");
        outStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("/home/temp/myfile.xml"));

        uCon = Url.openConnection();
        is = uCon.getInputStream();
        buf = new byte[size];
        while ((ByteRead = is.read(buf)) != -1) {
            outStream.write(buf, 0, ByteRead);
            ByteWritten += ByteRead;
        }
        System.out.println("Downloaded Successfully.");
        is.close();
        outStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Required File is not there  "+e.getMessage());            
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you've read the stream, you've read the stream. You can't re-read the stream more than once, without invoking the `mark()` and `reset()` methods and implementation of the `InputStream` class you're using should actually support this first.

Apart from that:

- Your try-catch statements needs:

  - To catch the proper exceptions and not just throw `Exception`, but rather -- `IOException`, `URLException`, or whatever's relevant (your IDE will recommend/fix this for you, if you remove the `catch (Exception e)` block).
  - A `finally` block which checks if the streams are not null and closes them.
- Your method should throws an IOException.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not closing your inputstream or your outputstream in a right way.
Always use

```
finally { 
    is.close(); 
    outputStream.close()
}
```

Comment: and for debugging: don´t use catch(Exception e), because you can´t figure out which exception was thrown, catch all exceptions individually.

Comment: Besides, using "catch(Exception e)" is a no-go, and it is one mayor exception-handling-anti-pattern (google for unchecked exceptions) and should never be used like this!